# How to integrate a watch process into MS Build and dotnet watch run

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, watch, msbuild-task, .net-6.0

There are CLI tools (external to .NET) that works in watch mode, e.g: `sass --watch` or `tsc --watch` etc.

**How do I integrate a custom tool in watch mode into MS Build (.csproj), so that it works with `dotnet watch run` and hot reload?**

Let's take ASP.NET Core as an typical example. I currently invoke the tool on each build instead watch mode

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
      <!-- How to execute `mycustomtool --watch` ? -->
      <Exec Command="mycustomtool" />
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I'm searching about this and I can't find a elegant way of doing this!

Comment: nope :( But from what I know, you will have to implement custom task in .NET Assembly, similar to TypeScript.Tasks.dll in [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild](https://nuget.info/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/4.7.3) nuget package. Unfortunately, I did not find source codes for it.

Comment: Let me know if you find something, I'll researching as well, if I know something I'll post here ok!